# change color of UITableView cell text populated with core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I am populating from CoreData.  I have tried changing the cell.label.text and cell.detailLabel.text color in IB but nothing happens.  It remains the same default gray.  I have also tried

```
NSManagedObject *device = [self.tableDataMainView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 cell.detailTextLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];

return cell;
```

but that doesn't work either.  I am using prototype cell in the tableView and subtitle in the cell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this code? It should be in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: It is.  I also get the text for the textlabel from the coreData objectForKey there too

Comment: Sorry I wasn't in front of my computer.  This was not in will displayCell  so I tried it using                                                                                                        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:    (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    
}  But no go

Comment: try to set tint color to your desired color. or go for custom tableview cell. it can be use full and easily customizable

Comment: thanks set all the text color fields to white in IB and one of them turned the text white